# How to write mockito test for modelAttribute annotated functions

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have a dao class which fetches the data from the database and i am using @modelAttribute anotated function to use the fetched data in the UI. I was wondering how to write mockito test for this function.

```
@SpringBootTest
class HomeControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Mock
    private ProjectsDao projectsDao;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void homePageCatchesException_ifFeaturedProjectsAreNotFound() throws Exception {
        doThrow(new FeaturedProjectsNotFoundException("")).when(projectsDao).getFeaturedProjects();
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("featuredProjects"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("ProjectsNotFound"));
    }

}
```

This is the mockito test that i have come up with so far.

This is the controller which i wanted to test

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    private Urls home = Urls.home;
    @Autowired
    private ProjectsDao projectsDao;    

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String showHomePage() {
        logger.info("{}.{}", new HomeController().getClass().getPackage(), new HomeController().getClass());
        logger.info("Function: showHomePage(), Information: Displaying Home Page");
        return home.toString();
    }


    @ModelAttribute("featuredProjects")
    public List<Projects> displayFeaturedProjects(Model model) {
        logger.info("{} {}", new HomeController().getClass().getPackage(), new HomeController().getClass());
        List<Projects> featuredProjects = null;
        try {
            featuredProjects = projectsDao.getFeaturedProjects();
        } catch (FeaturedProjectsNotFoundException e) {
            logger.debug("Function: displayFeaturedProjects, Information: Exception caught Projects not found");
            model.addAttribute("ProjectsNotFound", e.getMessage());
        }
        logger.info("Function: displayFeaturedProjects, Information: displaying features projects");
        return featuredProjects;
    }
}
```

I wanted to test if the model ProjectsNotFound is added so that i can display in the UI if the projects are not found. But when i mock the projectsDao class to throw an exception it is not adding the ProjectsNotFound attribute to the model.
Can Someone help me?

Comment: Try `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` on the `ProjectsDao`

Comment: No it didn't work but thanks for the reply though